# XLSX conditional formatting in Go

Tags: excel, go, xlsx

I'm using

> github.com/tealeg/xlsx

and it does not have conditional formatting options like this [python writer](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html) . Are there any packages in Go for conditional formatting? If not, what would be a good starting point to achieve this using the mentioned Go excel writer.
Thanks

**Edit 1**
I need a way so that the xlsx file "remembers" the conditional formatting for a cell range. I don't want to hard-code the condition to my Go program.

Comment: What is the problem with my question? Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you're able to format the cell or cell value, it's just a question of adding the condition yourself isn't it ?

Comment: No it isn't, if I write to a cell the way You mentioned, and save the file. Later on, if someone opens the file e.g. Excel 2013 or similar and let's say changes a value on which the condition was based, the condition will not be  called because the condition was hard-coded in my Go program.